# can a perl script be written to receive data from any of (1) file, (2) stdin, (3) redirect?

Tags: perl, redirect, pipe, filenames

Several unix utilities, such as fmt, head, and cat, can receive data in any of 3 ways: a filename; a pipe from standard input; or a redirect "<". For instance:

```
printf '%b' 'dog \ncat \nrat\n' > dogcatrat
fmt dogcatrat
cat dogcatrat  | fmt
fmt < dogcatrat
```

Can one write a perl script that will behave with the same versatility? Or is there a good reason not to attempt this? And is "pipe from standard input" the right way to refer to the line of code that starts with cat?

I want to write myfmt.pl, to be used in any of these three ways.

Comment: uh, yes? If you have an argument, read from that file, otherwise read from stdin.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the use case that the special filehandle `ARGV` addresses.

Comment: Nit: `cat dogcatrat  | fmt` and `fmt < dogcatrat` both feed `fmt`'s STDIN. There's no difference between the two as far as `fmt` is concerned.

Answer (score 5):

The `ARGV` special filehandle will do this by default. It is also the handle used by readline (aka the `<>` and `<<>>` operators) when not given a handle. So this is actually pretty common in Perl scripts.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.022;
use warnings;
while (my $line = <<>>) {
  # $line from one of the filenames passed as an argument, otherwise STDIN
  # $ARGV is the current filename, or - when reading from STDIN
}
```

You can use the `<>` operator instead to support older versions of Perl, but the `<<>>` operator [added in Perl 5.22](https://perldoc.pl/perl5220delta#New-double-diamond-operator) is a better option for this task if available, because the standard `<>` operator allows passing strange things like `date|` to run processes rather than read files.

For safer filename-only operation while supporting older versions of Perl, you could use [ARGV::readonly](https://metacpan.org/pod/ARGV::readonly) or emulate the `<<>>` operator like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
unshift @ARGV, '-' unless @ARGV;
while (my $file = shift) {
  my $fh;
  if ($file eq '-') {
    $fh = \*STDIN;
  } else {
    open $fh, '<', $file or die "open $file failed: $!";
  }
  while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    # ...
  }
}
```

(Technically the `<<>>` operator also does not allow passing `-` as an argument to read STDIN, but it is your choice if you want to allow that.)

Comment: It will even read from multiple files if multiple files are provided, just like `cat`, `grep`, etc.

Comment: What the answer doesn't make it clear is that you can use `use strict; use warnings; while (my $line = <>) { ... }` if you want to be compatible with older versions of Perl. But don't make setuid scripts (or scripts used by setuid scripts) that use `<>`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the following script fills the bill.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.18.2;
local $/ = ""; # input record separator: one paragraph at a time
while (<>) {
    print;
    print "\n";
    say '-' x 30;
}
```

Example:

```
printf '%b' 'dog \ncat \nrat\n' > aaa
try.pl aaa
cat aaa | try.pl
try.pl < aaa
```